# Strip off word pattern at the end of string using sed

Tags: bash, command-line, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have following string:

```
ksh -x SCRIPT2.ksh $BUSSINESSDATE & PID=$!; ksh -x SCRIPT1.ksh $BUSSINESSDATE & PID=$!;
```

I want to strip off the last word `& PID=$!;`. Desired result is:

```
ksh -x SCRIPT2.ksh $BUSSINESSDATE & PID=$!; ksh -x SCRIPT1.ksh $BUSSINESSDATE
```

**Note**: that I do have `& PID=$!;` in the middle of the string, I only need to get rid of the last word which contains `& PID=$!;`

I am using `sed` achieve this. But it doesn't seems to produce the expected output.

```
sed 's/\(\& PID=\$\!\).*$//'
```

Comment: Try `sed 's/& PID=$!;\s*$//'`

Comment: @Costas It works. But wondering what does "\s" in the middle does in your command?

Comment: `\s*` is zero or more white-space characters. You might not need it. It seems Costas was being extra careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/& PID=\$\!;$//'
```

The `$` toward the end anchors it to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

All answers are good so far, but for this concrete example you can save your time and write a few characters less:

```
sed 's/ & [^ ]*$//'
```

or even better

```
sed 's/ & \S*$//'
```

Comment: @mikeserv `.{9}$` is only 5, so definitely the best one! :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the last occurrence of a pattern on a line, you can just squeeze it.

```
sed 's/\(.*\)& PID=$!;/\1/'
```

That will match as much as possible in `\1` before matching the string so it will always strip only the last occurrence - regardless of whether or not the string you strip is actually at the end of the line.

Your attempt:

```
 sed 's/\(\& PID=\$\!\).*$//'
```

...does something like the opposite. It strips all characters on a line beginning with the first occurrence of your string and following on to the end of the line.

Remember the *leftmost-longest* rule - a regexp will always begin its match as far to the left in the string as it might and continue to match for as long as it might.

---

Note that if you want to remove just `n` last characters then with gnu `sed`

```
sed -E 's/.{9}$//'
```

Here `-E` option is necessary to use extended regular expressions.

Comment: @jimmij - you should probably give up the `-r` habit. The `-E` syntax is compatible with GNU and BSD `sed`s *and* should be POSIX as well if/when [this](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) ever takes effect.

Comment: Yes, probably. But `-E` is not documented neither in `man` nor in `info`, at least for my GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: @jimmij - yup, that remains an undocumented feature*(?)*. And it actually is *slightly* less capable - as near as I can tell the only thing you can do with `-r` that you cannot do w/ `-E` is switch from a BRE context to an ERE context. With `-r` you can do `sed -e 's/BREhere\(.*\)/w \1 portable backrefs/' -er 's/(nowERE).*/and \1 backrefs only as a non-POSIX extension/'`. While the backrefs w/ ERE still work w/ `-E` you can't switch from BRE to ERE like that. And even w/ `-r` you can't switch back to a BRE context anyway.